# iOS app with custom VPN connect

Tags: ios, vpn, openvpn, pptp, l2tp

i want to create app which can connect to VPN using PPTP, L2TP or OpenVPN, but i cant find any information about this. Only found infortmation about using IPSec and IKEv2 in ios 8 SDK.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to connect programatically in ios 8 you can use only IPSec or IKEv2 protocols. L2TP and PPTP protocols are private for apple. It is not possible to use L2TP and PPTP APIs in your applications. Only Apple is currently using these APIs.