# Creating PPTP VPN on iOS Programatically

Tags: ios8, vpn

I have tried to create VPN connection programatically and I followed this [link](http://ramezanpour.net/post/2014/08/03/configure-and-manage-vpn-connections-programmatically-in-ios-8/) its working fine with IPSec.

Now I want to create PPTP connection, is it possible to create with ios? if yes can one help me?

Comment: Why negative mark is there, please share me the details.

Answer (score 1):

To quote answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/26775461/5479839

> If you want to connect programatically in ios 8 you can use only IPSec
>   or IKEv2 protocols. L2TP and PPTP protocols are private for apple. It
>   is not possible to use L2TP and PPTP APIs in your applications. Only
>   Apple is currently using these APIs.